# fix xml file with invalid characters, Invalid xmlChar value 2 [9]

Tags: r, xml, httr, xml2

I am parsing xml-files from a webservice, and occasionally I encounter this error:

```
xml2:::read_xml.raw(rs$content) # where the object rs is the response from the webservice, obtained using the httr package

Error in read_xml.raw(x, encoding = encoding, ...) : 
  xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 2 [9]
```

I downloaded thousands of xmls and only a few are broken. '

My question is then:

How to locate the characters in the response that causes the error.
And what is the genral strategy to fix an invalid xml caused by invalid xmlChars?

I have sircumvented the problem by paring the response as a html, but I would rather fix the issue and parse as xml

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by doing the following:

first to get to peek inside the content of the httr response

```
xml_broken <- readBin(rs$content, what = "character")
```

Then I was able to systematically delete data from the broken xml, until I finally found this string of text which caused the problem:

```
"&#x2;" # from the context i could see that this should be parsed as the danish character 'æ'
```

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references I could see that this should in fact be encoded as

```
"aelig;"
```

so finally the httr content can be parsed by doing

```
rs$content %>% 
  readBin(what = "character") %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "&#x2;", replacement = "aelig;") %>%
  XML::xmlParse()
```